# detect if SQL COUNT(*) statement has new value

Tags: php, mysql

how can i detect if the COUNT has new value?

i wold like to alert if the COUNT number has been changed

```js
$ntcount =  "SELECT status,COUNT(*)
FROM selection WHERE status = 1 ";
$qnote = mysqli_query($link,$ntcount);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the criteria is for being alerted.  For instance how often is this to be checked or is whenever the user clicks on something?

Comment: Store the number in a database and compare?

Comment: normally you'd use a `trigger` to perform an action when a new row is inserted

Comment: i wold like to check if a new row with status = 1 has add to the database and if so to trigger alert or echo somthing

Comment: Save the old count in a session variable, and check if the new count is different.

Comment: Why are you selecting `status`? It's always going to be `1`, since you have `WHERE status = 1`.

Comment: i had a feeling that i am not in the right direction... any suggestions how can i make it work?